# BizTalk AS2EDI track EDI message

Tags: biztalk, edi, edifact, biztalk-2020

We are using an AS2 connection both for receiving and sending EDI messages. We configured the communication to be encrypted/compressed and signed.

Is it possible to track the EDI messages

- on receive - after decryption and compression on send?
- before encryption and compression?

With the built in tracking tools you can see the message in xml format. But it would be useful to have them in EDI.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes.  With BizTalk almost anything is possible and especially utilizing BAM with EDI - You should be able to view as native too.  You can log the EDI message in X12 format...  parse it and send to a database, email it...  the possibilities are many.  With Pipeline components you can log the message before anything happens to it or before the final send.